# Vue show props in bind component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

Child

```js
    Vue.component('xms',{
      template : `<div> {{errorMsg}} </div>`,
      props : {
       errorMsg : '',
       minLength : '',
      }
     }
    )
```

Parent html

```
<xms errorMsg="Error min : {{minLength}} " minLength="5"><xms>
```

**I want output**

" ***Error min : 5*** "

Answer (score 1):

First correct your definition:

```
 Vue.component('xms',{
  template : `<div> {{errorMsg}} </div>`,
  props : {
   errorMsg : String,
   minLength : Number,
  }
 }
)
```

Then fix the dynamic binding:

```
<xms :errorMsg="'Error min : ' + 5" :minLength="5"><xms>
```

Comment: I'd recommend putting `{{ minLength }}` in the template next to `{{ errorMsg }}` and just doing `<xms errorMsg="Error min:" minLength="5"><xms>` without the `v-bind` colon.

Comment: It's on the target. In my view, there is no need to pass minLength, just errMsg enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should define minLength in parent component not in parent template
In parent component:

```
data: {
minLength: 5,
}
```

For me, I just pass the min length in to child  component, after that we can add a message
In child component:

```
props: [minLength],
data: {
errMessage: 'Error ' + this.minLength
}
```